# Thread responses are swapping in weblogic deployed application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, weblogic

I opened this question by deleting the my post, where I asked question wrongly including title and provided not much information.My problem is thread request and responses are swapping in some cases.

Below are the application weblogic logs and the code

From the logs I found that threads are swapping.. Below are the weblogic logs
say two threads(7,8) processing performX() for two portIds (1234,4567)

```
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:55:45,319 [ExecuteThread: '7'----]  processing data for port id = 1234
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY,319 [ExecuteThread: '8'----]  processing data for port id = 4567
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '7'----]  ResponseQueue :: getResponse() ::  ResponseQueue456
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '7'----]  ResponseQueue :: getResponse() :: Reading Data from stream :: ResponseQueue456
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '7'----]  ResponseQueue :: getResponse() :: Reading Data from stream completed :: ResponseQueue456
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '7'----]:: ReturnXML=<xml>---<order_number>4567</order_number> ---</xml>
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '7'----]:: Adding ordernumber as Key = 4567 value = ReturnXmlObjet1234
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '7'----]:: Getting object of port Key = 1234 value = null
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '8'----]  ResponseQueue :: getResponse() ::  ResponseQueue456
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '8'----]  ResponseQueue :: getResponse() :: Reading Data from stream :: ResponseQueue456
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '8'----]  ResponseQueue :: getResponse() :: Reading Data from stream completed :: ResponseQueue456
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '8'----]:: ReturnXML=<xml>---<order_number>1234</order_number> ---</xml>
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '8'----]:: Adding ordernumber as Key = 1234 value = ReturnXmlObjet4567
<DEBUG> 2016-05-11 16:XX:YY [ExecuteThread: '8'----]:: Getting object of port Key = 4567 value = ReturnXmlObjet1234
```

If you see clearly thread 7 and thread 8 are swapping , as the map value for thread 7 is coming null, we are throwing applicationspecific error.
Below is the code. How to avoid this scenario.

I am abstracting the real time production code and logs.

```
Class A{
 ----

 B bobj = B.getInstance()     

 Map map = new HashMap();
 public void performX(String portid){
    logger.debug("Processing data for portId = "+ portId);
    returnXml = bobj.getResponse(); // bobj is a singleton
    logger.debug("returnXML ="+  retunrXML);
    ReturnXmlObjet r_obj = convertToObject(returnXMl);
    // retunrXml contain a field orderNumber which must be same as 
    // portid method parameter
     if(r_obj != null){
        logger.debug("Adding ordernumber as Key = "+ r_obj.getOrderNumber()+ "Value is =" + r_obj);
        map.put(r_obj.getOrderNumber,r_obj);
      } 
    r_obj = map.get(portid);
    logger.debug("Getting object of port Key = "+ r_obj.getOrderNumber()+ "Value is =" + r_obj);
    if(r_obj == null){
       throw new ApplicationSpecificException("Not able to get       Response");
    }
 } 
}

Class B(){

B instance = null;

public static synchronized BgetInstance() throws AboxRetryException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new B();
        }
        return instance;
    }

public synchronized  String getResponse() {

    logger.debug(" ResponseQueue :: getResponse() :: "+ this);
    String returnXML = null;
    String strResponseACK;
    InstantLinkXML ilXML = new InstantLinkXML();

    try {
        logger.debug(" ResponseQueue :: Reading Data from stream :: "+ this);
        returnXML = in.readLine();
        logger.debug(" ResponseQueue :: Reading Data completed from stream :: "+ this);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("Failure getting Response");

    } catch(Exception e){
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    if (returnXML != null) {
        // Send ACK
        strResponseACK = ilXML.getxxx();
        out.println(strResponseACK);
    }

    //code to convert XML to Java object.. ReturnObject has a property    port_db

    return returnXML;
}


Below is the code for *in* object initialization. This login() method is called in the class constructor where getResponsed() method is written

public String logIn() {
        String returnXML = null;
        try {
            String strUser = ConfigItemsAccess.getConfigItems("o2.xxx.user");
            String strPass = ConfigItemsAccess.getConfigItems("o2.xxx.password");
            String strServer = ConfigItemsAccess.getConfigItems("o2.xxx.server");
            int iPort = Integer.parseInt(ConfigItemsAccess.getConfigItems("o2.xxx.respport"));
            logger.debug("logIN :: strUser="+strUser+" strPass="+strPass+" strServer="+strServer+ " iport = "+ iPort );
            String strLoginRequest;
            String strLoginAck;
            InstantLinkXML ilXML = new InstantLinkXML();


            try {
                XXXSocket( Just a SOCKET object abstracted according to application) = new Socket(strServer, iPort);
                xxxSocket.setKeepAlive(true);   //new
                out = new PrintWriter(xxxSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(xxxSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                logger.error("Cannot connect to host: " + e.getMessage());



     } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to:" + strServer + ":" + iPort);
                    // Connect to Secondary Server
                    strServer = ConfigItemsAccess.getConfigItems("o2.xxx.server.backup");
                    try {
                        logger.debug("Connecting to Secondary Server: " + strServer);
                        xxxSocket = new Socket(strServer, iPort);
                        xxxSocket.setKeepAlive(true);   //new
                        out = new PrintWriter(xxxSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(xxxSocket.getInputStream()));
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
                        logger.error("Cannot connect to host: " + e2.getMessage());

}
} 
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    logger.error("Couldn't get I/O for the Secondary connection to:" + strServer + ":" + iPort);
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            strLoginRequest = ilXML.getLogInRequest(strUser, strPass);
            out.println(strLoginRequest);
            try {
                strLoginAck = in.readLine();
                returnXML = strLoginAck;
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                logger.error("Failure getting Comptel Ack back");

            } catch(Exception e){
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }


        }
        catch (FinderException Ex) {
            logger.error("FinderException trying to get o2.xxx from CONFIGITEMS\n" + Ex.getMessage());
            throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("Exception trying to get config items");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return returnXML;
    }

    ilXML.getLogInRequest(String strUser, String strPass){
return ("<Message version=\"SAS3\">\n" + "  <LOGIN\n" + "    LOGIN=\""
                + strUser + "\"\n" + "    PASSWORD=\"" + strPassword + "\"/>\n" + "</Message>\n");

    }
```

Socket Read the information from an EjbApplication(JAR file)

Please can you help me, what might be the root causes for this issue and how can I fix it.
Let me know still need more information.

Comment: *"If you see clearly thread 7 and thread 8 are swapping , as the map value for thread 7 is coming null ..."* -  Actually, I DON'T see that. Please explain what you are saying.

Comment: processing data for port id = 1234 which runs in thread 7, processing data for port id = 4567 runs in thread 8, after calling getResponse(), thread 8 returnxml is coming as part of thread 7 response and thread 7 returnXml coming as part of thread 8(returnXml = getReponse())

Comment: But the response XML comes from here `returnXML = in.readLine();` .   I ask again, where is the (real) evidence of "swapping"?

Comment: [ExecuteThread: '7'----]  processing data for port id = 1234
[ExecuteThread: '8'----]  processing data for port id = 4567
---
---
[ExecuteThread: '7'----]:: ReturnXML=<xml>---<order_number>4567</order_number> ---</xml>

[ExecuteThread:8'----]:: ReturnXML=<xml>---<order_number>1234</order_number> ---</xml>

above are the weblogic production logs, replcaed actual values with sample values

Comment: for thread 7 input(portID: 1234) , return xml contains order number 4567(thread 8 response),   for thread 8 input(portID: 4567) , return xml contains order number 1234(thread 7 response),

Comment: You are missing the point.  There is no evidence of swapping.  The XML is produced by reading >>something<< from >>some unspecified stream<<.  Unless you explain where `in` is set up and what it contains, your output is not credible evidence of ... anything.

Comment: Sorry Stephen.. I am  adding the code related in my actual question, May be I used the SWAP word incorrectly, May be sequential execution is correct word. In actual production  in multiple threads coming and  executing performX() not sequentially as real time load is high(which contain some more non synchronized method calls nothing to do with returnXml, hence i didn't represented those in post),

Comment: I refer you to your first comment.  That >>appears<< to be all about what `returnXml` is.  If this is irrelevant, why did you even bring it up?  Anyhow, I'm giving up on trying to understand you.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. for your comments, got the problem..
for Thread 7 input port 1234, it taking 6 secs time to get response from other system(i.e Socket Stream in.ReadLine()), In the mean while thread 8(for port 4567, is processing immediately) is modifying the request, hence(in.readLine()) reading the stream of thread 8 response and assigning to Thread 7 returnXml

Answer (score 1):

It looks like returnXml is being declared outside of your method. When you call getResponse() you're overwriting whatever was there before.

Comment: Also, I just noticed you're using three different variants of spelling for "returnXml" in performX(), so I'm guessing now that was all just fat fingering when porting over from production.